# google maps can I control what information is included on my map using api?

Tags: google-maps

Is there some way I can control the information included on the map using the API interface?

It seems both the normal map view and the satellite view contain information that is included only as one zooms in.  For example if one looks at the following map...

https://www.google.com/maps/@42.8538824,-89.4993582,17z/data=!5m1!1e4

you should see the National Ice Age Trail near Belleville WI.  But as you zoom out that information vanishes.

To be clear I want to somehow include this trail in my api/javascript generated map regardless of the zoom level.

Comment: Either build your own list and display them as markers (and maybe disable their display via map styling) or manage everything with the map style but : you can hide POIs at certain zoom levels where they usually show, but you cannot force show them on a smaller zoom level where they don't show by default.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Experiments with the API show that the Ice Age trail is a local.road feature and as such is lumped in with other local automobile routes.  Thus there is no way to style the Ice Age trail without affecting real local roads.  And there must be different zoom levels associated the Ice Age trail and real local roads and are beyond the reach of API stylers as  pointed out by MrUpsidedown.  So the only approach is to switch to server side maps;  I will leave that for another day.  I will accept amunramoto's reply and not delete this item as it may help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [zoom-level customization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/cloud-customization/zoom-levels) for certain categories of POIs that gives you some control over this.

Comment: True, but you cannot force show a POI category on smaller zoom levels where they don't show by default. If you were able to do that, for example show all business POI on zoom level 1, the map would become quite an unreadable mess...

Comment: @MrUpsidedown: So are you saying that if I get a google loud ID I can not make the zoom level smaller?